# million transaction - improve performance of website

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, performance, soap

I have a page that calls a Stored procedure to read 3 to 4 million data, make some calculations and return a small data table. The SP is slow approx. 20 to 30 sec. therefore, overall page load is slow.

Will i re-factor the SP? but problem is that whatever i do my end result will be the small Datatable.

Is there any suggestion to improve the performance?

Comment: Any more details?  Why does the procedure have to read 3 to 4 million records?  What is the table structure and the query being run?

Comment: You didn't even post the database engine being used.  How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: reading 3-4 million rows *will* take time - Are that may rows really read or is that the numbers of rows in the table? Perhaps an index would help? Please post what database you are using.

Comment: I have been using SQL Server 2008. the SP script is created for aggregating data from more then 5 tables. cursor is avoided and I need group by all the data to make small data table. It is actually a matrix like data table.

Comment: but i can run this sp in back ground before loading this page. will it be a good idea to use SOAP?

Comment: the resuld of SP also depends on parameter and parameter also depend s on User and user call also change the parameter. so result is dynamic.

Comment: That is slow.  Do you have an index on the columns that you matter.  Also google search on how to optimise sql queries.  It can make a HUGE difference.

Answer (score 1):

If the table is not updated so often make a "aggregated" table that have better performance.

Comment: I have been using SQL Server 2008. the SP script is created for aggregating data from more then 5 tables. cursor is avoided and I need group by all the data to make small data table. It is actually a matrix like data table.

Comment: but i can run this sp in back ground before loading this page. will it be a good idea to use SOAP?

Comment: @Shuvra: with aggregated table, @Pasi probably means that you should store the end-result table (the small one) somewhere into the database in a separate table designed just for this. So querying it would be super fast. A background job on your server would then refresh the data in that table from time to time, so no need to include SOAP in the mix.

Comment: Thanks Pasi and fretje. It is really a good idea. thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @Shuvra: You can accept an answer if you think it helped you with your specific question (welcome to Stack Overflow btw).

Answer (score 1):

If you're churning through 3 or 4 million rows of data and actually doing real work,  20 or 30 seconds is pretty decent performance, IMHO. Check the execution plan of your stored procedure. In the ideal world every table would be getting hit with index seeks rather than table scans. Consult with your DBA if you're not sure how to interpret the showplan results. I assume you're using SQL Server.

Check to make sure your tables have appropriate indices and that the statistics are up to date. Update them if not. Recompile the stored procedure. Parameters passed to the stored procedure can bollux up the cached execution plan, if the are oddball values. You can prevent this by coding your stored procedure like so:

```
create proc myProc

  @p1 varchar(32) 

as

  declare
    @p1Local varchar(32)

  set @p1Local = @p1

  ...
```

Comment: I have use index in tables and query plan seems ok. but i can run this sp in back ground before loading this page. will it be a good idea to use SOAP?

Comment: What does SOAP have to do with how the execution time of a stored procedure?

Comment: Sorry, I have very small idea about WCF/SOAP. actually I am working on web application. therefore, I am thinking, the page where this SP should call and load the dataset. instead of doing that if i call the SP in previous page then the user may see the actual page is loading faster then normal. the SP parameter is selected in log on time. by this way i can slaidly improve the performance. Is it a good idea? any more suggestion. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your data does not get updated too often, you can create an indexed view.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx:

> indexed views provide additional performance benefits that cannot be achieved using standard indexes. Indexed views can increase query performance in the following ways:
>   Aggregations can be precomputed and stored in the index to minimize expensive computations during query execution.
>   Tables can be prejoined and the resulting data set stored.
>   Combinations of joins or aggregations can be stored.